# How to indicate an error if it crossed maxlength in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

In my form I used `maxlength` for input fields, also I used jquery.validate.js to indicate some error messages.

- If I used `maxlength` alone in my html, small pop up appears only.
- If I used validate alone, I will get proper error messages but the user can enter more than the limit.

Nevertheless I don't want these scenarios actually...

What I need is once it reached to its `maxlength`, It should show an error message and it should not allow the user to enter more than 40 characters.

I don't want to use jquery custom function likes calculations `on keyup`!

I have tried with the following code:

```
<form id="myForm">
<input name="myName" required maxlength="40" />
</form>
```

my jQuery code as follows:

```
$("#myForm").validate({
    rules :{
        myName :{
            required :true,
            maxlength:40
        },
    },
    messages:{
        maxlength:"You crossed a maximum limit"
    }
});
```

Comment: http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2009/2/10/An-Introduction-to-jQuery-and-Form-Validation-2

Sorry, maybe I'm not totally understanding your question. maxlength already helps to keep the user from adding more than 40 characters right?

Comment: [This might help](http://jqueryvalidation.org/maxlength-method/)

Comment: if your elem is having the `maxlength="40"` then user is not able to put more than 40 characters right.

Comment: Ya that is correct.But i need to show error message to user when he try to enter more than 40 characters

Answer (score 0):

- Remove the HTML 5 attributes from your `input` element.  You don't need them when you've already declared the same rules within `.validate()`.  I think the automatic HTML 5 browser validation messages were confusing you while troubleshooting your broken jQuery Validate.
- When you specify custom messages using the `messages` option, you **must** also specify the input `name`, similar to the `rules` option formatting.   Within `messages` only the rule names are optional.  In other words, you can place a custom message on the input `name` itself and it will automatically apply to all rules for that input.  However, you cannot place a custom message on a rule that's unassigned to an input as you had done.

Otherwise, I don't see a problem in your code...

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/a5vBU/**

**HTML**:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input name="myName" />
</form>
```

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myForm").validate({
        rules: {
            myName: {
                required: true,
                maxlength: 40
            }  // <-- removed trailing comma
        },
        messages: {
            myName: {  // <-- need input name
                maxlength: "You crossed a maximum limit"
            }
        }
    });
});
```